# Batch save image files with different filename in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, batch-file, save

I am doing doing some batch processing to an image file set which demands that the files should be saved with an additional "_corrected" string in the end of the filename, for instance 'IMG_001.tif' should be saved after processing as 'IMG_001_corrected.jpg'.

Here goes my code:

```
FileList = dir('srgb8bit/*.tif');
N = size(FileList,1);

for k = 1:N

   % get the file name:
   filename = FileList(k).name;
   I = imread(filename);
   Icorr = CorrectedRetinexFM(I,8);
   ** Here should go the save command**
```

preferrably being able to choose a different directory to save them to. How is that possible?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Your code to read the images doesn't work, as the file.name field only contains the name of the file, not the path to it. You'd need `filename = ['srgb8bit/' FileList(k).name];`. You can create the file you want to save it to in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Use [fileparts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) to split the file name and its extension:

```
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(FileList(k).name);
```

Note that `pathstr` is "" since you already stripped that.

And then [imwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) like this

```
imwrite(Icorr, [name '_corrected.jpg']);
```